# C++ concept isn't easy to use?

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

I needed to specify a concept for Messages - very simple as long as it has a typeTag static member - see below, I simply write - and I do not think I am supposed to write much more than this if concept is easy to use:

```
template <typename M>
concept MessageC = requires(M m) {M::typeTag;};
```

then I have trouble for a straightforward use:

```
template <MessageC Message>
    void send(Message&& m){...}
```

The concept turns out to be not usable when `Message` is deduced to be `Finish&`, where `Finish` is actually a `Message` type. `Finish&::typeTag` is ill-formed as the g++ 9 compiler complains. 
I could do things like remove_reference in the concept definition except I do not know that is the recommended way. Is C++ Concept meant to be simpler to use than that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your concept is best written this way:

```
template<typename M>
concept MessageC = requires { typename M::typeTag; };
```

*i.e.* you need `typename` for the dependent name, and there is no need for arguments in the `requires` expression.

When it comes to your actual question:

```
template<MessageC Message>
void send(Message&&) {}
```

is equivalent to:

```
template<typename Message>
void send(Message&&) requires MessageC<Message> {}
```

but, as you noted, `Message` is a forwarding reference, which can collapse to either lvalue or rvalue references.

Therefore, your function should read:

```
template<typename Message>
void send(Message&&) requires MessageC<std::remove_reference_t<Message>> {}
```

consistently with the language rules.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to remove the reference in the concept itself?

Comment: @NicolBolas Maybe. For me it is easier to understand this way. In the end, it's just a matter of convention, isn't it? Furthermore, the basic standard library concepts do not remove references.

Comment: "*Furthermore, the basic standard library concepts do not remove references.*" Sure they do. Just look for `remove_cvref`; you'll see it a bunch.

Comment: @NicolBolas That's true. But I was thinking of `std::same_as` and the like, which I think do not remove cv qualifiers.

Comment: `same_as` is asking the question of whether two types are the same. `int` and `int&` are not the same and thus should not be `same_as`. But my overall point is that concepts in the library are fine with being passed references; `random_access_iterator<T>` works just as well as `random_access_iterator<T&>`. The invoker of the concept doesn't have to remove the reference. Thus, the C++ convention is that, if a concept logically works the same for a `T&` as a `T`, it is the concept's responsibility to handle references, not the caller's responsibility to remove them.

Comment: @NicolBolas Makes sense.

Comment: got it - I will play along then, Thx!

Answer (score 1):

> I could do things like remove_reference in the concept definition except I do not know that is the recommended way.

The standard does it plenty of times. It doesn't usually do this specifically for member typedefs and such, but that's because the standard typically uses traits classes to get "members" of a type, so that fundamental types could be used in those cases. Pointers don't have a `value_type` method, so the concepts library instead uses `iterator/readable_traits`.

Concepts are still C++; you can't just ignore rules of the language. Statements in concepts still must follow the rules of C++. A concept's template parameters work just like any other template parameters.

Comment: yeah - that is what this is about. Thx

Answer (score 1):

I end up writing the following to limit the typeTag static value within 2 bytes

```
template <typename M>
concept MessageC = std::remove_reference<M>::type::typeTag >= 0x0
    && std::remove_reference<M>::type::typeTag <= 0xffffu;
```